# Web API 2 not working (404)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

i have been trying for a long time get Web API 2 working. I have read a lot of articles and posts over internet, but so far i have been unlucky.

I just need to get working simple Web API method, but for some reason i am still getting 404 method not found. I really dont know now, where problem can be as it seems to me everything is ok.

I have tried a lot of variations of attributes, configs and so on. I have end up with this code:

Global.asax

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {  id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

ApiController

```
public class ContactFormController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/sendemail")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public IHttpActionResult SendEmail(ContactFormModel contactForm)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class ContactFormModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery Code

```
var jsonData = { "Name": name.val(), "Email": email.val(), "Subject": subject.val(), "Message": comment.val() };

$.ajax({
    url: "api/sendemail",
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    cache: false,

    ...
});
```

As you can see, it is MVC 5 + Web API 2.

Thanks for help. So simple thing and nothing is working.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

please update your global.asax like here:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

}
```

and change `[Route("~/api/sendemail")]` to `[Route("/api/sendemail")]`

Comment: Api routes must evaluate first, or you need to create more strict mvc routes (such that the framework doesn't attempt to look for 'ApiController'.) This is not MVC5-specific behavior

Comment: You are awesome!!! It works, only i had to remove starting / from suggested route [Route("/api/sendemail")]. I will accept this as answer.

Comment: Starting from an empty project, I was missing the FilterConfig and RouteConfig part. Adding those classes based on the template did the trick.

Comment: I would like to add something to this, I lost half the morning on the 404 issue, all the answers seemed not working for me since i had all the needed components. In my case i registered the normal routes before webapi routes, this seemed to overrite the api routes and not recognize them, so after switching the two it finally worked.

Comment: Routes cannot start with `/` apparently. I get an error when global tries to bind. Not sure what the heck is going on but been trying to solve this issue all morning *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

For me routing attributes were not working with WebAPI because I had the URL Rewrite module installed in my web.config.  Somehow the global routing templates were working with that in place but not the routing attributes above each web method.  I removed the `<rewrite>` section from within the `<system.webServer>` section in web.config and the routing attributes started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a Web API 2 project that was being published in a sub-folder of the domain name, which hosted its own ASP.net project.  The web.config from that main application was inherited into the web.config of the Web API 2 project, which interfered with routing.  To solve the problem I [stopped web.config inheritance completely](http://www.dondraper.com/2010/02/how-to-stop-inheritance-of-webconfig-files/) in the main project.

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
    <system.web> 
    … 
    </system.web> 
  </location>
```